# Enforcing JVM GC - for a good reason (I hope)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Let's look at potential race condition related to garbage collection speed.

Initial state:

```
main => a
a => b
b => c
```

**main** program references object **a**, object **a** references **b**, **b** references **c**. Now, we want to make **a** reference **c** instead of **b**.

Good:

```
a => c
```

As **b** is no longer referenced, it can be garbage collected.

Bad:

```
a = null
a => c
```

In between these two steps (setting **a** to null and re-pointing it at **c**), **b** may become garbage collected together with **c**. I doubt these kind of errors may be picked up by unit tests, as GC most likely won't run quickly enough to run into troubles. One way to detect the problem would be to enforce GC, or at least increase its frequency. Is there any command line param or another means of doing it? If not, what other automated means of preventing such kind of errors have we got?

Comment: It isn't easy to answer your question given the "hand waviness" of the description. A specific code example would be more useful.  That said, just because there is no reference to "b" does not mean it is collectible. To be collectible "b" must be "unreachable" from any of the garbage collection roots. Here is a good discussion of how it works. https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/

Comment: I would look into Java's `AtomicReference`.

Comment: How would you make the assignment `a = c;`, if you hadn’t a reference to `c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're plain wrong. Even "in between these two steps", there's a reference to `c` *somewhere* (hint: google for GC roots).

What you describe would imply a sure and fast crash for all java-running servers, but there's no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting a reference within A to refer to C, how is it possible that C does not have a reference already in your program (a local variable or something at the very least) Are you getting C from thin air? The Garbage Collector won't even consider C for garbage collection.